# jinja2 print to console or logging

Tags: python, template-engine, jinja2

I'm kind of new to Jinja2 and am wondering if there is a way to make the templates, while being generated, to print to the console or redirect some output to some kind of stream?

Since Jinja2 templates may have logic inside, I think it would be useful sometimes to log some info in to some kind of logfile, or at least get printed to console.

Is this possible or am I just talking garbage?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you can achieve it using filters (http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters) or extensions (http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/#adding-extensions). The idea is to just print the filter or extension straight to console.

Not tested but the filter should be something like:

```
def debug(text):
  print text
  return ''

environment.filters['debug']=debug
```

To be used as:

```html
...<p>Hello world!</p> {{"debug text!"|debug}}...
```

Remember to remove the debug on production code!

Comment: oh cool! I knew there should be some way to achieve it. Now, I have an issue with this. I can't send literal strings to the custom filter, I can achieve it with a {% set text="debug text!" %} tag, and then {{ text | debug }}. I don't know if literal strings may be sent to filters or not... :-o

Comment: well, partially solved it (or perhaps that's the way it should be) using '()' to enclose all the string I need to print. For example {{ ("debug text!") | debug }}. Or more precisely: {{ ("debug text! value: "~valueINeedToLog) | debug }}

Answer (score 18):

A similar but slightly different approach using context processor:

In python / flask:

```
@app.context_processor
def utility_functions():
    def print_in_console(message):
        print str(message)

    return dict(mdebug=print_in_console)
```

In jinja2, Use it anywhere as follows:

```
{{ mdebug("any text or variable") }}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would have an HTML element with an id set and the attribute of hidden for the element. Then use JavaScript as such

```
<p id="hidden-p">{{a_variable}}</p>
<script>
    var hiddenP = document.getElementById("hidden-p").innerHTML;
    console.log(hiddenP);
</script>
```